# How can I query a database from MS Word without an odc file?

Tags: sql-server, ms-word, odbc, connection-string, oledb

I want to retrieve data from a SQL Server database into MS Word. I can accomplish that by using the [DATABASE field code](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-database-field-04398159-a2c9-463f-bb59-558a87badcbc) by inserting the following into the special brackets created by pressing CTRL+F9, then executing the query as a table in MS Word by pressing F9:

`DATABASE  \d "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\My Data Sources\MyDataSource.odc" \c "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MYSERVER;DATABASE=MYDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" \s "SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM MyTable"`

This works locally because I've configured MyDataSource.odc to use the SQL Server driver, but I'd like this to work on the computers of my colleagues without that dependency. *Is it possible to make this feature work without specifying a Office Data Connection file?*

Here's the relevant section of my ODC file:

```
<xml id=docprops><o:DocumentProperties
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <o:Description>MyDescription</o:Description>
  <o:Name>MyName</o:Name>
 </o:DocumentProperties>
</xml><xml id=msodc><odc:OfficeDataConnection
  xmlns:odc="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:odc"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <odc:Connection odc:Type="ODBC">
   <odc:ConnectionString>{SQL Server};SERVER=MYSERVER;DATABASE=MYDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;</odc:ConnectionString>
   <odc:CommandType>Table</odc:CommandType>
   <odc:AlwaysUseConnectionFile/>
  </odc:Connection>
 </odc:OfficeDataConnection>
</xml>
```

The [DATABASE Code Field documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-database-field-04398159-a2c9-463f-bb59-558a87badcbc) tells me the \d switch is *"Used for all database queries except a query to an SQL database table using ODBC"*, but only provides examples of connecting to databases held within a file but not to a SQL Server Database.

The use case is we must regularly send a list from a database to a 3rd party that only receives files in MS Word format. I'd like anyone on the team to be able to open the file & update it, or even better, automate within O365 Sharepoint / Power Automate, and this DATABASE field would accomplish that if only it weren't tied to a specific file on my computer.

Note that I can connect to the data in question using this connection string. For example, I can connect using this code in Excel's Get & Transform (Power Query): `= Odbc.Query("Driver={SQL Server};Server=MYSERVER;Database=MYDB", "SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM MyTable")`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the piece of documentation you reference is out of date and has probably been invalid since about 2000.

Idon't think there is a way to avoid having an external file (see below), but I believe it is still possible to use a completely empty .odc file (e.g. just create a zero-length text file and rename it as empty.odc, and store it at a known location). Then put all the other necessary connection info. in the `\c` parameter. Whether that is workable may depend on whether you can persuade the necessary people to let you do it. In principle, you could provide a separate bit of VBA code or some such to set up such as file in a known location as a one-off.

The background...

For some reason, Microsoft made it impossible to specify a "server type data source" in Word MailMerge, or in its DATABASE field, just using the Provider (OLEDB) or Driver (ODBC) name + other necessary information such as the server name, database/schema name and so on. You always had to provide something external to Word.

For an ODBC data source, you either had to provide the name of a Machine DSN (either a user DSN or System DSN), or you had to provide a file DSN in a .dsn file. Or you could use the OLEDB Provider for ODBC data sources, and then you would need a .odc file.

For an OLEDB connection, you had to have either a .udl file or a .odc file.

For a while it was possible to specify a blank FILE:= parameter when opening a MailMerge data source in VBA, and provide a Machine DSN in the Connection:= parameter. I am not sure that is true any more. But in any case, AFAIK it has long been impossible to do the equivalent in a DATABASE field, i.e. omit `\d` or specify `\d ""`

Even if you could get an ODBC connection to work, there is another snag, which is that Word doesn't "see" data in SQL Server Unicode column types if you use ODBC. (Except maybe if you go via the OLEDB Provider for ODBC, which I understood was deprecated).

FInally, as far as I know, the built-in facilities in Word do not allow you to insert the authentication details for a user in either a database field or a .odc (or a DSN) using any kind of encryption. Which is not an issue for local Windows authentication but may well be an issue in any other circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

`DATABASE` fields can use any datasource that can be used for a mail merge.

You can simplify and make your `DATABASE` field more portable by coding along the lines of:

```
{DATABASE \d "{FILENAME \p}/../ MyDataSource.CSV" \s "SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM MyTable" \l "9" \b "63" \h}
```

This will allow the field to reference a datasource that is kept in the same folder as the document containing the `DATABASE` field (in the above example, `MyDataSource.CSV`. Note that the field braces for the `{FILENAME \p}` field must also be created via <kbd>Ctrl-F9</kbd>.

The `\l`, `\b` and `\h` field switches can be used to control the output format. See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-database-field-HP010260104.aspx. That link refers to a 'Table AutoFormat dialog box', which you can access via Insert|Quick Parts|Field>Database. You'll need to set up a connection to the datasource before you can access the dialogue.

For a working example, see:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21847-mail-merge-into-different-coloumns.html#post67097

Comment: That's a great example of how to use a relative path to a local file, but I'm trying to connect to SQL Server without needing a local ODC file. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: So what's it supposed to read, if not a specific file? Regardless, neither a DATABASE field nor anything else you might want to use will work without a specific file to extract the data from.